# How to create a pointcut that filters on the type of the caller?

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

Is it possible to create a pointcut that only applies when the method is called from a particular class?

I only want the aspect to be run when the calling context is a particular type...

Comment: You are referring to a method called `foo()` for example and you have a pointcut `execution(* *..foo())` and you want to restrict this pointcut to certain types that have method `foo()`?

Comment: look at cflow, and cflowbelow. they pick out this exact case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, for basic scenarios I would recommend using within:

```
call(* someMethod(..)) && within(SomeContainingClass)
```

"call to someMethod made from within SomeContainingClass"

For a more dynamic scenario where your class calls some secondary class that *then* invokes the method of interest, I would use cflow:

```
call(* someMethod(..)) && cflow(execution(* *(..) && within(SomeType))
```

"call to someMethod whilst in the control flow of a method executing in SomeType"

The latter adds some runtime cost to the checking, whilst the former is fully statically determinable (at weave time).

Comment: looks like it will fit just fine